# Loss of data while ordering an unordered_map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map

I have a `unordered_map<string, int> freq`  and I order it transforming it into a 
`map<int,string> freq2`. I use the next function in order to do that:

```
map<int, string> order(unordered_map<string, int> x) {
    map <int, string> map;
    for (auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it) {
        map.emplace(it->second, it->first);
    }

    return map;
}
```

the size of the `unordered_map`is 2355831 and the returned `map` is 505, so as you see the loss of data is quite big and i have no idea why....
Any idea why this happens?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks to all, you are all right, I have a lot of int with same value, that´s why i loose the data( really stupid from my part to not see it before)

Comment: Besides ordering you're inverting the map. Now think for a moment what the implications are. And post an [mcve].

Comment: Because map excludes duplicate keys, I suppose...

Comment: So you are effectively swapping keys and values. Are your values (integers) all unique? If not, you need a `multimap`.

Comment: Because you have 505 unique integers among 2355831.

Comment: why on earth you would like to ordering an unordered map? Why no use a ordered map like `std::map`?

Comment: Small tip: `order(const unordered_map<string, int>& x)` makes sure you don't waste CPU time and memory (temporarily) make an unnecessary copy of the caller's `unordered_map` for `order`'s `x` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is because there are duplicates among the `int` values. Try replacing `map<int, string>` with `multimap<int, string>`.

Answer (score 1):

The code itself looks fine. However, since you are mapping from string keys to integers, it might be very well that you have multiple keys with the same value.

From the documentation of `emplace`:

> The insertion only takes place if no other element in the container has a key equivalent to the one being emplaced (keys in a map container are unique).

So if a lot of your entries in the first map have the same value (which is the key in the second map), then your dataset will decrease by a lot.

If you need to preserve those elements, then `std::map` is not the right container.